# In a wpf app, hide window and then show the same instance of the window when called from another window

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is how it should work:

Window1: A button click opens a new window and hides the current window
(This page contains a few textboxes)

```
public void applyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
...
    DataDisplay dd = new DataDisplay();
  dd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
...
}
```

New Window: A button click opens Window1 from the same state (all the checkboxes, and textbox should contain the values from the time it was closed)

```
  private void settings_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Filters filter = new Filters();
            filter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
//As you can see I am calling a new instance instead of reopening the same hidden instance.
```

Instead of creating a new instance every time, I'd prefer to use the same instance every time. If any other not so complicated ways out there, feel free to shoot!

Comment: What have you tried? Your question needs to include a good [mcve] that shows clearly what the context is, what you've tried, and also include a precise description of what the code is doing now and what you want it to do instead. I don't see any reason you can't just treat your question as a form of pseudo code and write the code. The `Window` class does, after all, have `Show()` and `Hide()` methods on it. Why can't you just call them at the appropriate time?

Comment: I've made a few changes. Please, take a look at it.

Comment: That's not an [mcve], never mind a good one. I can say, if you want to show a `Window` object you've hidden, you need to save that object's reference somewhere, so you can reuse it.

Comment: Let me try googling that. It would be awesome if you could provide me an example of storing an object's reference.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think it would be better to have a "MainWindow" managing the 2 changing windows You could have it handled on the 2 Windows events or by using delegates:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static frmFilters filterWindowInstance = new frmFilters(OpenDataDisplay);
    static frmDataDisplay dataWindowInstance = new frmDataDisplay(OpenFilters);

    static void OpenFilters()
    {
        filterWindowInstance.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        dataWindowInstance.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    static void OpenDataDisplay()
    {
        filterWindowInstance.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        dataWindowInstance.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFilters();

        Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

}

public partial class frmFilters : Window
{
    Action CloseFilterOpenData;

    public frmFilters(Action CloseFilterOpenDataToSet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CloseFilterOpenData = CloseFilterOpenDataToSet;
    }

    private void cmdHideThis_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseFilterOpenData();
    }
}

public partial class frmDataDisplay : Window
{
    Action CloseDataOpenFilter;

    public frmDataDisplay(Action CloseDataOpenFilterToSet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CloseDataOpenFilter = CloseDataOpenFilterToSet;
    }

    private void cmdHideThis_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseDataOpenFilter();
    }
}
```